# Не отправляется сообщение по SMTP

Tags: perl

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw(:standard);
use Net::SMTP;

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";

$smtp= Net::SMTP->new('smtp.mail.ru') ;

$smtp->auth('log','pass');

$smtp->mail("from@mail.ru");
$smtp->to("to@mail.ru");
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("To: to@mail.ru");
$smtp->datasend("From: from@mail.ru");
$smtp->datasend('Subject: tema1 \r\n');
$smtp->datasend("\r\n");
$smtp->datasend("HELLO WORLD. \r\n");
print $smtp->message();
$smtp->dataend();

$smtp->quit();
```

Comment: Нужны данные кроме скрипта, что выводится в броузере.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том что вы используете двойные кавычки для строк которые содержат специальный символ @.

Либо ескейпте этот символ:

```
$smtp->mail("from\@mail.ru"); 
$smtp->to("to\@mail.ru"); 
$smtp->data(); 
$smtp->datasend("To: to\@mail.ru"); 
$smtp->datasend("From: from\@mail.ru");
```

Либо используйте одинарные кавычки:

```
$smtp->mail('from@mail.ru'); 
$smtp->to('to@mail.ru'); 
$smtp->data(); 
$smtp->datasend('To: to@mail.ru'); 
$smtp->datasend('From: from@mail.ru');
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать авторизацию, так как для пользователей mail.ru почта должна доставлятся и без авторизации

Comment: пробовал -ругается...

немного переделал и ввел через пересенные :
my $serv='smtp.mail.ru';
my $to_mail='to@mail.ru';
my $from_mail='from@mail.ru';
 
$smtp= Net::SMTP->new(Host=>$serv) ;

и запахало...
 спасибо всем за содействие !